# htaccess redirect POST message to php file in subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess

I hope someone can help me to correct my htaccess problem in a shared hosting scenario, so I don't have access to httpd.conf. I am trying to redirect a POST to /process-dev.php to the file in the correct subfolder as shown below, but instead my POST gets redirected to index.php 
The POST comes from the webpage itself (actual domain replaced with subdomain1.com) https:://www.subdomain1.com.

```
/
|- .htaccess
|- css
|- clientscripts
|- php
|- site
    |- subdomain1.com
        |- language
            |- default
                |- process-dev.php
                |- index.php
```

My htaccess file

```
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on

# Enforce SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# Handle non-www URLs
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain1\.com [NC,OR]
# Handle www URLs
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.subdomain1\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?(process-dev|post-file-dev|post-image-dev)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ site/subdomain1.com/language/default/$1.php [L,QSA]

# Redirect all to the Application if not done already
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?site/subdomain1\.com/language/default/index\.php [NC]

# or if request is a real file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# or if request is a real directory but not the root directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite the rest to the index.php file in your public folder
RewriteRule ^.*$ site/subdomain1.com/language/default/index.php [NC,L]
```

The partly output of print($_server)

```
map(
'ONECOM_DOMAIN_NAME'=>'subdomain1.com',
'ONECOM_DOMAIN_ROOT'=>'/customers/6/6/d/subdomain1.com/',
'SCRIPT_NAME'=>'/site/subdomain1.com/language/default/index.php',
'REQUEST_URI'=>'/process-dev.php',
'QUERY_STRING'=>'',
'REQUEST_METHOD'=>'POST',
'SERVER_PROTOCOL'=>'HTTP/1.1',
'REDIRECT_URL'=>'/process-dev.php',
'SCRIPT_FILENAME'=>'/customers/6/6/d/subdomain1.com/httpd.www/site/subdomain1.com/language/default/index.php',
'SERVER_NAME'=>'subdomain1.com',
'HTTP_REFERER'=>'https://subdomain1.com/',
'HTTP_ORIGIN'=>'https://subdomain1.com',
'HTTP_SCHEME'=>'https',
'HTTP_HOST'=>'subdomain1.com',
'HTTPS'=>'on',
'ONECOM_TMPDIR'=>'/customers/6/6/d/subdomain1.com//tmp',
'DOMAIN_NAME'=>'subdomain1.com',
'ONECOM_DOCUMENT_ROOT'=>'/customers/6/6/d/subdomain1.com/httpd.www',
'DOCUMENT_ROOT'=>'/customers/6/6/d/subdomain1.com/httpd.www',
'REDIRECT_STATUS'=>'200',
'REDIRECT_HTTPS'=>'on',
'REDIRECT_ONECOM_TMPDIR'=>'/customers/6/6/d/subdomain1.com//tmp',
'REDIRECT_ONECOM_DOMAIN_ROOT'=>'/customers/6/6/d/subdomain1.com/',
'REDIRECT_ONECOM_DOMAIN_NAME'=>'subdomain1.com',
'REDIRECT_DOMAIN_NAME'=>'subdomain1.com',
'REDIRECT_ONECOM_DOCUMENT_ROOT'=>'/customers/6/6/d/subdomain1.com/httpd.www',
'REDIRECT_DOCUMENT_ROOT'=>'/customers/6/6/d/subdomain1.com/httpd.www',
'PHP_SELF'=>'/site/subdomain1.com/language/default/index.php',
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies in

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?(process-dev|post-file-dev|post-image-dev)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ site/subdomain1.com/language/default/$1.php [L,QSA]
```

You are using `$1` but there is no grouped pattern in the RewriteRule (`^.*$`), you ment to use `%1` to refer to a group in the earlier `RewriteCond`.

Also, i'm not sure if you really ment to put that **second** `?` in the RewriteCond pattern ? I doubt you wanted that part of the uri to be optional in order to match this rule.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I have tried to replace $1 with %1, and removed the last ? but unfortunately I still end up on the index.php page

Comment: your suggestion got me to try out a few things, and I managed to get it to work now using your suggestions. I have updated my post with the answer based on your recommendation. thank you for your help

Comment: "with that group being optional, the condition will match **any** possible uri" - it won't match "any URI" (because of the trailing end-of-string anchor). By making the group optional then it will also match the document root (which would result in the request hitting `index.php` in the OPs updated solution). However, the **first** `?` is certainly _redundant_ since the `REQUEST_URI` var _always_ starts with a slash.

Comment: No the first `?` being redundant is not true; it varies based on whether the rewrite is done in the apache config, or in a .htaccess file in any of the directories from the webroot on down, so prefixing with `^/?` is actually a good habbit. -- that said, yes i missed the fact that the ending was also anchored (`$`) and thus it wouldn't match much at all.

Comment: @Raxi You are thinking of the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ - this does vary depending on context (_server_ or _directory_) - but that is not being tested here. However, the `REQUEST_URI` server variable _always_ contains the root-relative URL-path starting with a slash - regardless of context.

Comment: Ah yea, you're correct, i was thinking of the rule -- i stand corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Raxi suggestion I got it to work with this change

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?(process-dev\.php|post-file-dev\.php|post-image-dev\.php)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ site/subdomain1.com/language/default/%1 [L,QSA]
```

Thanks to MrWhite for mentioning this way to post a working solution to the problem based on feedback received